# How to transfer Image (Blob) via LipeRMI?

Tags: java, android, mysql, blob, rmi

I have a android application and corresponding server connected via RMI (LipeRMI to be specific).
I have a MySQL database connected to Server component, server is local. I have written code to download the image stored in database. The image is stored in Blob format, and at server I am converting it to InputStream but since it is not serializable I cannot pass it via RMI to the android client.

Please suggest some way to send the Blob data to android client from server and then convert it to bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `com.mysql.jdbc.Blob`'s `getBinaryData()` method which returns `byte[]`, so it can be transferred.